# Django custom user model does not work on live server

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, pythonanywhere, django-custom-user

I am extending the user  model, and it works on my local server but does not work on Heroku, nor does it work on Python anywhere. I am using Postgres. It's a fresh database. I can't even run a makemigration due to this error. My setting file also have the

error:

```
(mysite-virtualenv) 06:21 ~/go-all-nations-2-backend (main)$ python manage.py makemigrations
/home/evolvingtech/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/environ/environ.py:784: UserWarning: Error reading /home/evolvingte
ch/go-all-nations-2-backend/.env - if you're not configuring your environment separately, check this.
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/evolvingtech/go-all-nations-2-backend/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/evolvingtech/go-all-nations-2-backend/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/evolvingtech/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_f
rom_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/evolvingtech/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/evolvingtech/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/evolvingtech/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/evolvingtech/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 301, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/evolvingtech/go-all-nations-2-backend/app_backend_api/models.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User, AbstractBaseUser, _user_get_all_permissions, AbstractUser, AbstractBaseUser, Group, Permission, 
UserManager, _user_has_module_perms,_user_has_perm
ImportError: cannot import name '_user_get_all_permissions' from 'django.contrib.auth.models' (/home/evolvingtech/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/
lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py)
```

models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
#geo-location
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
# needed for the custom based tokens
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

REGEX_PHONE_NUMBER = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\d{10}$', message="PHONE MUST BE 10 DIGITS: '4731234567'.")

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    org = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Settings file:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "app_backend_api.CustomUser"
```

Any thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Check the order in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`.

Make sure `django.contrib.auth` is first in the list, and your own apps after the `django.contrib` apps.

Comment: I have that in place. The only item that differs between prod and dev is the Postgres database. Dev is local Prod is hosted. Not sure why I am receiving this error

Comment: In that case, check the secrets/environment variables. This suggests some configuration issues.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of an error like that is that you are using a different version of Django than the one that the code was written for.